# GROUP BY one column and COUNT two columns

Tags: mysql, group-by, count

I need to group by a vendor id and count the qty that havent been sold or failed but also count the sold amount for that vendor.

```
|---vendor id---|---failed---|---sold---|
|    1234       |   FAILED   |          |
|    9876       |   FAILED   |          |
|    1234       |   GRADE A  |   sold   |
|    1234       |   GRADE A  |   sold   |
|    9876       |   GRADE A  |   sold   |
```

I've tried countless queries I have found on stack and Im just not having any luck.

```
$sql = 'SELECT *,sold,COUNT(sold),COUNT(*) FROM wp_drives WHERE sold != "sold" AND grade != "Grade FAIL" GROUP BY vendor_id';
```

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td style='text-align: center;'>" .$row['vendor_id']. "</td>";
    echo "<td style='text-align: center;'><span class='qty'>".$row['COUNT(*)']."</span></td>";
    echo "<td style='text-align: center;'>" .$row['capacity']. "</td>";
    echo "<td style='text-align: center;'>" .$row['form_factor']. "</td>";
    echo "<td style='text-align: center;'>" .$row['rpm']. "</td>";
    echo "<td style='text-align: center;'><span class='sold'>".$row['COUNT(sold)']."</span></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

In my table I have the vendor grouped, with a qty of all the hdd in that group and then some are sold and need to show how many have been sold in that group. Right now its just returns the same value to sold as it does to qty.

Answer (score 0):

you can't use `*` when you are grouping data, column which you are grouping should be part of select criteria. try this

```
SELECT vendor_id,COUNT(*) as count 
FROM wp_drives 
WHERE sold != 'sold' AND grade != 'Grade FAIL' 
GROUP BY vendor_id
```

Comment: To see sold count, change sold != 'sold'  to sold = 'sold'. I just prepared the above query based on yours

Comment: I think thats the issue here, I dont want to show sold in the qty left but only sold in the sold column.

Comment: I got your point now, since the WHERE clause is diff for qty and sold, you can't get qty by VendorId and sold qty by vendorId together. For qty, WHERE clause is sold != 'sold', and for 'sold', WHERE clause is sold = 'sold', both are completely different

Comment: Yeah, hmm. I may need to do multiple queries then, yeah?